# Move line in legend

Tags: matlab, graph, matlab-figure, legend

I have a cell array with four strings which is used as legend for four individual X,Y plots. One string is very long and therefore divided into a four-line legend by `sprintf`, The four plot legend is shown in the figure below. Is it possible to move the blue line up so it fits the first line, which is next to the 'Av.'

[image]

Here is a short example of code:

```
X=[2 4 6 8; 2 3 4 5; 4 5 6 7 ; 7 6 8 9];
Y=[1 3 5 7; 2 5 6 8; 8 6 4 2; 7 5 4 3];

Title = {
'123456789_1'
'ABCDEFGHIJ_1'
'123ABC_1'
sprintf('Av. \n(123456789_1 \nABCDEFGHIJ_1 \n123ABC_1)')
};

fig1=figure;
hold on
for i=1:size(X,2)
plot(X(:,i),Y(:,i));
end
hold off
legend(Title,'Orientation','vertical','Location','northeastoutside','FontSize',8);
```

Comment: Please add the code you use to generating the legend (a small example)

Comment: Hi Luis. I have included a small code in the question above, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I made some workaround and found this way:
create so much lines as your number of strings at legend and make them invisible.

```
% data example
x = [1:0.1:6.2]
% create plot. Let them be nan - they will not be shown at plot
plot(x, [x.^2; x.^3; x.^4; x.^5; nan(size(x)); nan(size(x)); nan(size(x))])
% create legend
[~,iconsH] = legend('f1','f2','f3','my','text','is','here');
% find picture of legend and make lines with such Tags invisible
cellfun(@(x) set(findobj(iconsH, 'Tag', x),'Vis','off'), {'text','is','here'})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick-and-dirty trick: split the multi-line string into different strings, and have the extra lines appear in the legend without an associated visible line.

```
X=[2 4 6 8; 2 3 4 5; 4 5 6 7 ; 7 6 8 9];
Y=[1 3 5 7; 2 5 6 8; 8 6 4 2; 7 5 4 3];

Title = {
'123456789_1'
'ABCDEFGHIJ_1'
'123ABC_1'
'Av.' % split into different strings
'(123456789_1 '
'ABCDEFGHIJ_1'
'123ABC_1)'
};

fig1=figure;
hold on
for i=1:size(X,2)
plot(X(:,i),Y(:,i));
end
for k=1:3 % 3 is the number of extra lines. Manually set
    plot(NaN,'color','none') % plot invisible lines with no color, will
                             % generate legend entries
end
hold off
legend(Title,'Orientation','vertical','Location','northeastoutside','FontSize',8);
```

[image]

Comment: you are faster again! Do you think my answer has any sense now?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam Oh, I didn't know it was doing a similar thing. I saw a previous version of yur answer without comments, and the code doesn't run as is (`x` is undefined). Yes, I think it's worth keeping, as it uses a slightly different approach